# GTK ComboBox set_active_text: assertion `GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am adding a MS Word-esque Combo Box to my application to allow the user to change the font size. Here is the setup code:

```
sizeBox = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
for size in xrange(MIN_FONT_SIZE, MAX_FONT_SIZE+1):
    sizeBox.append_text(str(size))

def UpdateFontSize(c, box):
    newSize = box.get_active_text()
    if newSize:
        self.textViewer.SetFontSize(int(newSize))

print sizeBox.get_active_text()
sizeBox.connect("changed", UpdateFontSize, sizeBox)
```

Running my program and trying to change the selected entry in the combo box gives me this:

```
None
OutNav.py:876: GtkWarning: gtk_combo_box_get_active_text: assertion `GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
   newSize = box.get_active_text()
```

So get_active_text works fine in the enclosing scope, but when I supply the ComboBox as an argument to the callback, it suddenly stops working. Can anyone tell me what is going on here? (I wanted to use a ComboBoxText as apparently gtk.combo_box_new_text is deprecated, but for some reason it isn't in my distribution of PyGTK 2.24)

Comment: Is `UpdateFontSize()` a method of a class?

Comment: UpdateFontSize is the callback method for the "changed" signal that I define inline.

Comment: I just realized I am passing the same ComboBox to the callback twice. Not only is that pointless, but somehow it was also causing my issue. (Not sure how this happened)